# Python: list to JSON

Tags: python, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use Django with [jquery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) but having trouble sending response.

Here is my code:

```
def ajax_tags_autocomplete(request):
    """ Autocomplete for tag list """
    beginning_of_title = request.GET.get('term', '')
    tags_found = Tag.objects.values_list('title', flat=True).filter(title__startswith=beginning_of_title)
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(tags_found), mimetype='application/json')
```

I get an error:

```
[u"php"] is not JSON serializable
```

Why? It is not possible to serialize a list? What should I pass to the serializer, then?

I would be greatful for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure it's actually a list containing unicode objects and not a list containing some database objects? The `u"php"` might just be the `repr()` of the object.

Try `json.dumps([unicode(t) for t in tags_found])` or `json.dumps(map(unicode, tags_found))`

Comment: It, actually, worked! Can you explain what happened there? I was sure that `values_list('title', flat=True)` gave me a normal flat list or strings.

Comment: `values_list()` returns list only after evaluation. Unless you evaluate it (`list(tags_found)` is the simpliest way), it will be queryset, which is not JSON serializable.

Comment: Nope, I'm not really familiar with Django or its ORM. But since it worked, it means Django returned a (probably plain) list containing some objects that are not plain str/unicode objects.